# Azure MobileServiceClient can InsertAsync but not ReadAsync

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I can create a MobileServiceClient and `GetTable<Model>()` to `InsertAsync`, and see how my model gets inserted in the Easy Table table in Azure. But when I `ReadAsync()` from the table I get the following error:

`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileSerices.MobileServiceInvalidOperation: The server did not provide a response with the expected content.`

This is when I `mobileServiceClient.GetTable<Model>.ReadAsync()`

What could be the problem?

This was when running from an MsTest project with no `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();` call. The read worked when running the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

According to [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/467):

`As @elamalani pointed out above, we don't support .Net Core 2.1 in the SDK today. Unfortunately, we don't have a workaround today and like Ela said, the we don't have an ETA for a new release or other SDK to use for .Net Core 2.1 compatibility yet, so your only workaround is to stick with .Net Core 2.0 for now.`

And I was also had SDK version 2.1

After changing **SDK to version 2.0** all going to work fine. Please try to making the same, hope it will help you

Comment: Indeed it helped to downgrade